# TextView not centering for large sets of text

Tags: java, android, xml, textview

I have a problem with TextViews.  I use the code below to center text both horizontally and vertically. But if I put too much text in, is no longer stays centered. How can I work around this?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
 <TextView
        android:id="@+XX/X"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="24dp" />
```

Comment: you need android:gravity="center" in the TextView tag

Answer (score 1):

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+XX/X"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="24sp" />
```